# How to download files headless in Selenium (Java) when download happens in new tab?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, download, headless

I have a web page where when I click a button it opens another tab and then in it, downloads a csv file after few seconds. I was trying to automate this headlessly but I am unable to do so. I am using the below code. But I think the below solutions is for download happening in same window. How can I tweak it to work in my situation?

The code works fine and the file gets download if i run this normally (non headless) by commenting out the line options.addArguments("--headless");

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", webdriverpath);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("--test-type");
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
    ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();


    HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);


    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);

    Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
    commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("behavior", "allow");
    params.put("downloadPath", downloadFilepath);
    commandParams.put("params", params);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    String command = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commandParams);
    String u = driverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" + driver.getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(u);
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));
    httpClient.execute(request);




    //OPEN URL
    //Click Button
```

Comment: Please edit the question so that it shows exactly what you tried and illustrates the manner in which it failed. Also, try running it with regular, non-headless Chrome and watching to see if you can see what the problem is yourself. Finally, make sure that your code isn't simply failing to wait long enough for the download to occur.

Comment: No its not waiting. Execution get completed. But the file wont get saved.

Comment: What I'm saying is that _not waiting_ might be the problem.

Comment: Its waiting. Normally files wont be saved if we download them heedlessly. (People say its a 'feature' of selenium) Above workaround is supposed to solved that. unfortunately in my case its not working, an i think its because my download happens in a newly opened tab as soon as i click the download button.

Comment: Hope you are using latest version on chrome and chrome driver. Download in headless mode supported from Chrome 77 https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Yeah, I checked and I am using latest versions of both. By the way, i understand what you said. But do u know if that is supposed to work in my case (the download happens on a newly opened tab, when i click the download button)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59678457/10262890 @automaticSoldier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for in Java :

Right after clicking the download button switch to new tab and also do a refresh :

```
    ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
    driver.navigate().refresh();
```

(In my case it worked without the refresh. So you mey try without that statement aswell)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when download in headless mode.(But working in non-headless mode)

And I found the solution (example in **Python**):

**First step - click Download button and switch to new tab:**

```
download_btn.send_keys(Keys.Control + Keys.RETURN)  //click button to download
print("windows count:", len(self.driver.window_handles)) //check how many windonws(tab)
print("window:", self.driver.current_window_handle)  //check current window
download_btn.send_keys(Keys.Control + "2")  //switch window to new tab
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[-1]) // using driver switch to last created tab
print("windows count:", len(self.driver.window_handles))
print("window:", self.driver.current_window_handle)
```

Output (to confirm that window has switched to new tab successful):

> windows count: 2
>
> window: CDwindow-9D0B0A86678939EE6EA89B4627016F5A
>
> windows count: 2
>
> window: CDwindow-43ACC6E22256C42592CD34E880A08079

**Second step - Config download behavior agian**

You can wrap below code to function and call it after switched to new tab.

```
params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_path}
print("Change default download dir to :", params['downloadPath'])
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)
```

**Third step - Reload the page (Important step)**

It will trigger download behavior.

```
 self.driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me! But ALL I DID WAS RIGHT AFTER CLIKING THE DOWLOAD BUTTON I SWITCHED TO THE NEW TAB. I didn't have to do the second and third steps at all!  (For the third step I think its is because in my case, the new tabs link is not actually download link. after opening the new tab within few second the that page will automatically refresh/redirect after the file was generated and that's when the download is triggered). Tough I am not sure why I was able to skip the second step.